# Unexpected Unicode Translation in Grails/Spring Integration App

Tags: java, grails, unicode, spring-integration, clob

I have a Grails app that includes a Java-based Spring Integration driven email adapter. The email adapter processes emails from a single source and, based on business rules, reports certain communications back to the user by updating some internal tables, including adding the HTML body of the email to an Oracle `CLOB` for reference.

About half the time, the links in the HTML are corrupted when they are added to the CLOB. For example, "**=df**" is interpretted as Unicode **U+00DF**, and converted to a "**ß**" (LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S) and "**=20**" is converted to a **space**. Both of these unexpected mappings break the links.

```
http://www.mycompany.com/MyProject/MyApp.xxx?field1=dfa1.0&field2=2.0&field3=20012345&field4=N

http://www.mycompany.com/MyProject/MyApp.xxx?field1ßa1.0&field2=2.0&field3 012345&field4=N
```

This corruption doesn't happen all the time and I haven't been able to identify a pattern to when it happens.

This is the only code that "touches" the content of the HTML from the email...

```
public void processMessage(Message<?> message) {
    if (message.getPayload() instanceof MimeMessage) {
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = (MimeMessage) message.getPayload();
        try {
            String subject = mimeMessage.getSubject();

            logger.info("Subject : " + subject);

            // Get the main body of the message -- Assumes the email is in HTML format and
            // uses that to isolate the interesting bits of the email to analyze
            String content = convertStreamToString(MimeUtility.decode(mimeMessage.getDataHandler().getDataSource().getInputStream(), "quoted-printable"));
            logger.info("Content Length (bytes) : " + content.length());
            int htmlStart = content.indexOf(HTML_START);
            int htmlEnd = content.lastIndexOf(HTML_END);
            String html;
            try {
                html = content.substring(htmlStart, htmlEnd + HTML_END.length());
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                // Don't try and prune the string
                html = content;
            }

            // Do the major processing of the actual HTML contents. This is where the magic happens.
            processHtmlMessageContent(html);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            logger.error("Error in processing message:", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error in processing message:", e);
        }
    } else {
        logger.error("DON'T KNOW HOW TO PROCESS [" + message.getPayload().getClass() + "] MESSAGE");
    }
    logger.info("Done.");
}
```

I suspect the issue is in `convertStreamToString` or `MimeUtility.decode`, but I haven't been able to isolate it. I'm also not ruling out some strangeness when this is stored in a `CLOB`, but I find this less likely.

For reference, my `convertStreamToString()` method is...

```
protected String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
    try {
        return new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    } catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

I tried changing...

```
String content = convertStreamToString(MimeUtility.decode(mimeMessage.getDataHandler().getDataSource().getInputStream(), "quoted-printable"));
```

to...

```
String content = convertStreamToString(mimeMessage.getDataHandler().getDataSource().getInputStream());
```

But now I've lost basic mime decoding.

I also tried using MimeUtility to get the encoding

```
String encoding = MimeUtility.getEncoding(mimeMessage.getDataHandler().getDataSource());
```

This returns `7bit` and I've tried using that, but then I wind up with things like `=3D` for equals signs.

In the decoded content, I get the following, which indicates `quoted-printable`

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

I've looked through the javadocs, source and online examples, but this really isn't clicking for me.

Answer (score 0):

The conversions you're seeing are exactly quoted-printable decoding, so I suspect you're trying to decode data that wasn't QP encoded in the first place. You should probably check the headers of the `mimeMessage` to decide what decoding you need to do, rather than just doing QP unconditionally.

Comment: I expanded my example to include the surrounding method. I'm not sure exactly what I should be using for the decoding... Should I replace `"quoted-printable"` with `mimeMessage.getContentType()`?

Comment: @GeoGriffin Actually, according to the [javadoc for MimeMessage.getDataHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getDataHandler%28%29) any required decoding should already have been done by the framework, so you don't need to call MimeUtility.decode at all.

Comment: I've updated the question with the things I've tried. Basically, I've removed `decode()` as you suggested, but I've lost basic mime decoding. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I've tried several different iterations of code changes and everything points back to using `quoted-printable`. I've updated the question to reflect things I've tried. Any concrete examples would be greatly appreciated.